# Navigating to detail view controller with storyboard in iphone sdk

Tags: uitableview, ios7, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I want to navigate from master view controller to detail view controller using following scenarios-

1. I want to create custom cell
2. In that cell I would like to create a button say "go to Detail"
3. My custom cell should be in table view by outlet from stroryboard.
4. User will tap on "go to Detail" and navigate to detail screen.

can anybody show me the way that how could I achieve such functionality. I'm new with storyboard. I have tried to see in stack but i'm unable to get proper guidance regarding it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First for making custom cell you have to add a empty xib file to a project and drop UITableViewCell control in it. Then add a another objective class in project that is sub class of UITableViewCell . Refer this class to UITableViewCell that you dropped in empty xib file . Set its identifier column to "Cell" and drop Go to Detail button on that cell .

In the class where you used UITableView put this code :

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCell" bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
CustomCell *cell =(CustomCell*) [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier ];

// Configure the cell...
[cell.btnDetails addTarget:self action:@selector(segueToAnotherView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
cell.btnDetails.tag = indexPath.row;
```

And now on the selector method you can segue to the class according to your need .